# C# XML Deserialize an Object containing an attribute and a list of string yields an empty list?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am currently attempting to deserialize the following mesage:

```
<Message Id="1234">
    <Body>This</Body>
    <Body>Is</Body>
    <Body>Test</Body>
    <Body>Text</Body>
</Message>
```

Using the Following object:

```
public class Message
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [XmlArrayItem("Body")]
        public List<string> data { get; set; }

        public Message()
        {
            data = new List<string>();
        }
    }
```

The object successfully deserializes, but, the Message.data.Count is 0.  I have tried adding an `[XmlArray(ElementName="Message")]` tag to data and still the string is empty.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `[XmlArrayItem("Body")]` to [`[XmlElement("Body")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class Message
{
    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Body")]
    public List<string> data { get; set; }

    public Message()
    {
        data = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

This tells `XmlSerializer` that the list is to be formatted as a one-level sequence of elements rather than a two-level nested list.

With `XmlArrayItem`, your XML would need to look like this:

```
<Message Id="1234">
    <data>
        <Body>This</Body>
        <Body>Is</Body>
        <Body>Test</Body>
        <Body>Text</Body>
    </data>
</Message>
```

Comment: This was it.  I never would have tried this.  Thank you!

Comment: You answered it faster than it will mark it as answered...I can't get a cheeseburger that fast!